# Nagios: How to aggregate a large amount of notifications into one email notifcation?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have a Nagios server which monitors many servers.
There's a dashboard which has been coded in-house and it sends monitoring data using passive checks to the Nagios server.
Whenever an issue occurs, the NOC team is being flooded with email notifications.

My aim is:

When an issue occurs, and even if the dashboard sends 100 notification emails to Nagios, I want Nagios to aggregate the notifications into one notification.
Then I expect Nagios to send one more notification when the issue is resolved.
How is it done?

Answer (score 3):

[Flapjack](http://flapjack.io/) is designed to help with this.

<strike>I'm pretty sure that Etsy's [Nagios Herald](https://github.com/etsy/nagios-herald) address this issue.</strike>  I'm told that what you want instead is the check_check.rb within the [ruby-nagios gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-nagios).  (H/T Ryan Franz)